# How to keep images in Mail for offline reading?

Tags: mail.app

For example:I subscribe emails to Huffington Post,and they send daily mails.How can I keep images in those mails so I can read them offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under **Mail / Preferences / Accounts** and selecting your account and then **Advanced**, you'll find an option to *Keep copies of message for offline viewing*.

Just choose **All messages and their attachments**.

[image]